# How do I get current running instance of AVPlayer after view dissapeared?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayeritem

I have built an app in iOS using swift which lists images, songs and PDFs of the client. The user can download these files and use them. For songs, the functionality is to let user download the file and once download is complete, let him/her play the file. The songs are listed in a `UITableView` by album name and on click of a cell I call a `.show` to show another `UITableView` with songs for that album. On click on a cell in the table, I check if the file is downloaded or not. If it's downloaded I open a view controller using `.show` which has all media player controls and media metadata.

I have implemented all media controls including repeat and shuffle functionality and the player plays continuously for all downloaded tracks. When I click back at the navigation bar, I destroy the instance of the `AVPlayer` and the songs aren't played in the background. I do this because if I don't the song keeps playing in the background and I do not know how to get the playback control of the song playing.

This is my view controller for the media player

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer

class AudioPlayer: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

    var downloadedTracks = [URL]()
    var playableAudioItems = [PlayableTrack]()
    var playableAudioItemsUnshuffled = [PlayableTrack]()
    var serviceAudioItems = [AudioItem]()
    var currentTrack: PlayableTrack? = nil
    var topLevelLabel = " "
    var avPlayerItem: AVPlayerItem?
    var player: AVPlayer?
    var currentTrackIndex = 0
    var commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
    var mpic = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default()
    var isRepeated = false
    var isShuffled = false

    @IBOutlet weak var albumArt: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var rewindButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var forwardButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleTrack: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var progressSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var previousTrack: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var nextTrack: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var albumName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var shuffleButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var repeatButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        downloadedTracks = CommonUtils.fetchAudioPaths()
        if (UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "AudioItems") as? Data) != nil {
            self.serviceAudioItems = UserDefaults.standard.retrieve(object: Array<AudioItem>.self, fromKey: "AudioItems")!
        }

        if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "TracksRepeatable") != nil {
            self.isRepeated = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "TracksRepeatable")
        }

        if UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "TracksShuffled") != nil {
            self.isShuffled = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "TracksShuffled")
        }

        self.mapValuesFromServiceToPlayable()
        if self.isShuffled {
            self.playableAudioItems.shuffle()
        }
        UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch _ {
            return print("error")
        }
        if currentTrack != nil {
            self.currentTrackIndex = self.playableAudioItems.firstIndex(of: self.currentTrack!) ?? 0
        }
    }

    func mapValuesFromServiceToPlayable() {
        self.playableAudioItems = [PlayableTrack]()
        for serviceTrack in self.serviceAudioItems {
            let fileName = URL(string: serviceTrack.trackURL)!.lastPathComponent
            for mp3FileURL in self.downloadedTracks {
                if mp3FileURL.lastPathComponent == fileName {
                    let track = PlayableTrack(
                        albumName: serviceTrack.albumName,
                        albumArt: serviceTrack.albumArtURL,
                        trackName: serviceTrack.trackName,
                        trackURL: mp3FileURL)
                    self.playableAudioItems.append(track)
                }
            }
        }
        self.playableAudioItemsUnshuffled = self.playableAudioItems
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
        self.mpic = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default()
        self.initialisePlayerAndPlay()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.finishedPlaying(myNotification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.avPlayerItem)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.player?.pause()
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
        self.destroyPlay()
    }

    func initialisePlayerAndPlay() {
        let playableTrack = playableAudioItems[self.currentTrackIndex]
        if self.player != nil {
            if self.player!.rate != 0.0 {
                self.destroyPlay()
            }
            self.progressSlider.setValue(0.0, animated: true)
            let origPlayImage = UIImage(named: "baseline_play_circle_outline_black_48pt")
            let tintedPlayImage = origPlayImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
            self.playButton.setBackgroundImage(tintedPlayImage, for: .normal)
            self.playButton.tintColor = KeyConstants.apsmDark
        }

        let imageURL = URL(string: playableTrack.albumArt.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))
        self.albumArt.sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView(true)
        self.albumArt.sd_setIndicatorStyle(.whiteLarge)
        self.albumArt.sd_setImage(with: imageURL)
        self.titleTrack.text = playableTrack.trackName
        self.albumName.text = playableTrack.albumName

        let origRewindImage = self.rewindButton.backgroundImage(for: .normal)
        let tintedRewindImage = origRewindImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        self.rewindButton.setBackgroundImage(tintedRewindImage, for: .normal)
        self.rewindButton.tintColor = KeyConstants.apsmDark

        let origPlayImage = self.playButton.backgroundImage(for: .normal)
        let tintedPlayImage = origPlayImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        self.playButton.setBackgroundImage(tintedPlayImage, for: .normal)
        self.playButton.tintColor = KeyConstants.apsmDark

        let origForwardImage = self.forwardButton.backgroundImage(for: .normal)
        let tintedForwardImage = origForwardImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        self.forwardButton.setBackgroundImage(tintedForwardImage, for: .normal)
        self.forwardButton.tintColor = KeyConstants.apsmDark

        let origPreviousImage = self.previousTrack.backgroundImage(for: .normal)
        let tintedPreviousImage = origPreviousImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        self.previousTrack.setBackgroundImage(tintedPreviousImage, for: .normal)
        self.previousTrack.tintColor = KeyConstants.apsmDark

        let origNextImage = self.nextTrack.backgroundImage(for: .normal)
        let tintedNextImage = origNextImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        self.nextTrack.setBackgroundImage(tintedNextImage, for: .normal)
        self.nextTrack.tintColor = KeyConstants.apsmDark

        let origShuffledImage = self.shuffleButton.backgroundImage(for: .normal)
        let tintedShuffledImage = origShuffledImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        self.shuffleButton.setBackgroundImage(tintedShuffledImage, for: .normal)
        if self.isShuffled {
            self.shuffleButton.tintColor = KeyConstants.apsmLight
        } else {
            self.shuffleButton.tintColor = KeyConstants.apsmDark
        }

        let origRepeatImage = self.repeatButton.backgroundImage(for: .normal)
        let tintedRepeatImage = origRepeatImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        self.repeatButton.setBackgroundImage(tintedRepeatImage, for: .normal)
        if self.isRepeated {
            self.repeatButton.tintColor = KeyConstants.apsmLight
        } else {
            self.repeatButton.tintColor = KeyConstants.apsmDark
        }

        let asset = AVAsset(url: playableTrack.trackURL)

        let assetKeys = [
            "playable",
            "hasProtectedContent"
        ]

        self.avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset,
                                         automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys: assetKeys)
        self.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: self.avPlayerItem)
        let playerLayer=AVPlayerLayer(player: player!)
        playerLayer.frame=CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 50)
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

        self.progressSlider.minimumValue = 0
        let duration : CMTime = self.avPlayerItem!.asset.duration
        let seconds : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
        self.progressSlider.maximumValue = Float(seconds)
        self.progressSlider.isContinuous = false
        self.progressSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.playbackSliderValueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)

        self.player!.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, preferredTimescale: 1), queue: DispatchQueue.main) { (CMTime) -> Void in
            if self.player != nil && self.player!.currentItem?.status == .readyToPlay {
                let time : Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player!.currentTime());
                self.progressSlider!.value = Float ( time );
            }
        }

        self.playTrack(self.playButton!)

        var image = UIImage(named: "baseline_audiotrack_black_48pt")
        if self.albumArt.image != nil {
            image = self.albumArt.image
        }
        let albumArt = MPMediaItemArtwork.init(boundsSize: image!.size, requestHandler: { (size) -> UIImage in
            return image!
        })
        self.mpic.nowPlayingInfo = [MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: playableTrack.albumName + playableTrack.trackName, MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: albumArt]

        self.commandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = true
        self.commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.playTrackFromLock))
        self.commandCenter.pauseCommand.isEnabled = true
        self.commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pauseTrack))
        self.commandCenter.stopCommand.isEnabled = true
        self.commandCenter.stopCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.destroyPlay))
        self.commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.isEnabled = true
        self.commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.clickNextTrack(_:)))
        self.commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.isEnabled = true
        self.commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.clickPreviousTrack(_:)))
        self.commandCenter.seekForwardCommand.isEnabled = true


    }

    @IBAction func playTrack(_ sender: Any) {
        if self.player!.rate == 0.0
        {
            self.playTrackFromLock()

        } else {
            self.pauseTrack()
        }
    }

    @objc func playTrackFromLock() {
        self.player?.play()
        let origPlayImage = UIImage(named: "baseline_pause_circle_outline_black_48pt")
        let tintedPlayImage = origPlayImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        self.playButton.setBackgroundImage(tintedPlayImage, for: .normal)
        self.playButton.tintColor = KeyConstants.apsmDark
    }

    @objc func pauseTrack() {
        self.player?.pause()
        let origPlayImage = UIImage(named: "baseline_play_circle_outline_black_48pt")
        let tintedPlayImage = origPlayImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        self.playButton.setBackgroundImage(tintedPlayImage, for: .normal)
        self.playButton.tintColor = KeyConstants.apsmDark
    }

    @IBAction func rewind(_ sender: Any) {
        let preferredTimeScale : Int32 = 1
        self.player?.seek(to: self.player!.currentTime()-CMTime(seconds: 5.0, preferredTimescale: preferredTimeScale))
    }

    @IBAction func forward(_ sender: Any) {
        let preferredTimeScale : Int32 = 1
        self.player?.seek(to: self.player!.currentTime()+CMTime(seconds: 5.0, preferredTimescale: preferredTimeScale))
    }

    @IBAction func clickNextTrack(_ sender: Any) {
        self.player?.pause()
        var toPlayNext = true
        self.currentTrackIndex += 1
        if self.currentTrackIndex >= self.playableAudioItems.count {
            if self.isRepeated {
                self.currentTrackIndex = 0
            } else {
                self.currentTrackIndex = self.playableAudioItems.count - 1
                toPlayNext = false
            }
        }

        if toPlayNext {
            self.initialisePlayerAndPlay()
        } else {
            self.destroyPlay()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func clickPreviousTrack(_ sender: Any) {
        self.player?.pause()
        var toPlayNext = true
        self.currentTrackIndex -= 1
        if self.currentTrackIndex < 0 {
            if self.isRepeated {
                self.currentTrackIndex = self.playableAudioItems.count - 1
            } else {
                self.currentTrackIndex = 0
                toPlayNext = false
            }

        }

        if toPlayNext {
            self.initialisePlayerAndPlay()
        } else {
            self.destroyPlay()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func clickSuffle(_ sender: Any) {
        if self.isShuffled {
            self.isShuffled = false
        } else {
            self.isShuffled = true
        }
        if self.isShuffled {
            self.playableAudioItems.shuffle()
        } else {
            self.playableAudioItems = self.playableAudioItemsUnshuffled
        }
        let origShuffledImage = self.shuffleButton.backgroundImage(for: .normal)
        let tintedShuffledImage = origShuffledImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        self.shuffleButton.setBackgroundImage(tintedShuffledImage, for: .normal)
        if self.isShuffled {
            self.shuffleButton.tintColor = KeyConstants.apsmLight
        } else {
            self.shuffleButton.tintColor = KeyConstants.apsmDark
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.isShuffled, forKey: "TracksShuffled")
    }

    @IBAction func clickRepeat(_ sender: Any) {
        if self.isRepeated {
            self.isRepeated = false
        } else {
            self.isRepeated = true
        }
        let origRepeatImage = self.repeatButton.backgroundImage(for: .normal)
        let tintedRepeatImage = origRepeatImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        self.repeatButton.setBackgroundImage(tintedRepeatImage, for: .normal)
        if self.isRepeated {
            self.repeatButton.tintColor = KeyConstants.apsmLight
        } else {
            self.repeatButton.tintColor = KeyConstants.apsmDark
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.isRepeated, forKey: "TracksRepeatable")
    }

    @objc func playbackSliderValueChanged(_ playbackSlider:UISlider)
    {

        let seconds : Int64 = Int64(playbackSlider.value)
        let targetTime:CMTime = CMTimeMake(value: seconds, timescale: 5)

        self.player!.seek(to: targetTime)

        if self.player!.rate == 0
        {
            self.player?.play()
            let origPlayImage = UIImage(named: "baseline_pause_circle_outline_black_48pt")
            let tintedPlayImage = origPlayImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
            self.playButton.setBackgroundImage(tintedPlayImage, for: .normal)
            self.playButton.tintColor = KeyConstants.apsmDark
        }
    }

    @objc func finishedPlaying(myNotification:NSNotification) {
        self.clickNextTrack(self.nextTrack!);
    }

    @objc func destroyPlay() {
        self.player?.pause()
        self.avPlayerItem = nil
        self.player = nil

        self.mpic.nowPlayingInfo = [MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: ""]
        self.commandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = false
        self.commandCenter.pauseCommand.isEnabled = false
        self.commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.isEnabled = false
        self.commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.isEnabled = false
    }
}
```

This is how I call the above controller:

```
let nextViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AudioPlayer") as! AudioPlayer
        nextViewController.currentTrack = currentTrack
        self.show(nextViewController, sender: Any?.self)
```

What I really want is to get the instance of the `AVPlayer` and `AVPlayerItem` of the song that is playing in the background so that I can regain control of the playback. Something similar to Amazon Prime Music player where the player minimizes on back button and expands again on clicking on the player.

Comment: I ended up using Singleton pattern

Answer (score 0):

Make the **"var avPlayerItem: AVPlayerItem?"** and 
    **"var player: AVPlayer?"** outside the class **"AudioPlayer"** as a global variable to access it on other view controller